# Python pandas dataframe can't delete int64 columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have loaded a dataset into a pandas data frame. I'd like to delete a column called `ID`, which is of type int64.  When I have tried to do so with:

`data = data.drop("ID", axis=1, inplace=True)`, but am getting the following error:

`KeyError: "['ID'] not found in axis"`

I suspect this has something to do with the fact that the column I'm trying to delete is of type int64, since this error is only occurring when I try to delete int64 columns.

What preprocessing do I need to do on this column to delete it?

Comment: It's probably the index. Try `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: After you load the dataframe what does df.info() show?

Comment: @cs95 -- Attempted: `data_frame = data_frame.reset_index(drop=True)
data_frame.drop("ID", axis=1, inplace=True)`, but no luck

Comment: @ScottBoston : df.info yields the following output: `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6875571 entries, 0 to 6875570
Data columns (total 30 columns):
ID                            int64
Case Number                   object
Date                          object
Block                         object

Comment: You already remove the index by the `reset_index(drop=True)`, no need for the second command.

Comment: no. You're supposed to already have solved this problem by calling reset_index().

Comment: Update your question with the outputs of df.info()

Comment: Another idea is that your column names have leading whitespaces, so try: `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` and then `df = df.drop('ID', axis=1)`

Comment: Oh.. another problem is you don't need to use inplace=True and set it to a variable. You drop statement above is incorrect.  `data = data.drop('ID', axis=1)` no inplace.

Comment: Performing reset_index(drop=True) on the data frame fixed the issue. Thanks, all

Comment: It's best if you show your dataframe for problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your "ID" column was your index column. This is not a typical column and so you cannot delete it using `drop`. The correct way to do so is using:

```
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
```